# Android Wear: Unfortunately, Dev Tools has stopped

Tags: wear-os

I have a working Internet connection on my Phone and it is connected fine to my Android Wear Emulator. However, Dev Tools and Speech Recorder Application on the wear emulator get closed with an error when I launch any of them from "Start". Also "Voice actions" on the Android Wear app installed on the phone are  not working. What is the issue?

Comment: What do you see in the logcat?

Comment: @CaseyB http://pastebin.com/4NRTmXKW -  I think line 25 shows the application launch